# How to reduce the size of React Native .apk file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app by using react native with react-native  that display my name on the screen. As I am compiling to Apk file. The size goes up to 27 MB. Is this normal? Are there any ways to reduce the size of the app ? Thank you guys

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-expo-react-native-app-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Change your engine to [Hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes) and you should see reduction in file size and many other performance improvements.

Follow [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#enabling-hermes) to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more about why the .apk file has such a large size, you can open it using an archive tool as you would use to open, e.g., a .zip file. Bundling a fresh react-native project I end up with an .apk of size 31.4 MB, so yes, I would say that this is normal. This is what my generated apk contains

- app-release.apk 100 %

  - okhttp3 0.064 %
  - kotlin 0.077 %
  - META-INF 0.33 %
  - assets 0.85 %
  - res 1.93 %
  - lib 89.77 %

    - **armeabi-v7a 19.32 %**
    - **x86 22.73 %**
    - **x86_64 26.14 %**
    - **arm64-v8a 23.86 %**

As you can see, the majority of the size comes from the sub-folders of the lib directory. These directories contain .so-files (compiled libraries) for different platforms. This is mentioned in the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#publishing-to-other-stores):

> By default, the generated APK has the native code for both x86 and
> ARMv7a CPU architectures. This makes it easier to share APKs that run
> on almost all Android devices. However, this has the downside that
> there will be some unused native code on any device, leading to
> unnecessarily bigger APKs.

If you want to reduce the size you look into using [Proguard](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#enabling-proguard-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-apk-optional) to reduce the size of the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Other than Hermes, you can try removing some libraries that can be replaced. From your question I can sense that your app is a simple basic app but if you do have any, you can try and see which libraries are taking a lot of storage space.

As for myself I removed @react-native-firebase/firestore and reduced about 5~10MB, along 5 minutes of build time (didn't realize it's such a massive pacakge, but to be fair, the firebase sdk v9 aims to solve this problem with [modular imports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade), but not supported by the react-native library yet).

On top of that, your question is likely a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630065/how-to-reduce-android-apk-size-in-react-native), so you can check this out.

Answer (score 0):

go to android\app\build.gradle and make this options true in addition you can also enable hermes

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

It will return emulator and release apks separately if you want all combine you can use .aab format rather then apk
. playstore uses .aab and installs app version suitable to user's mobile version.your 27mb file hardly will 7-8mb in actual build/installs in .aab but for personal use or testing solution above is preferable arm-v7 version of apk run almost every android phone so pick armv7 from release builds for installation